# Facebook Canvas App post data between multiple pages

Tags: facebook, canvas

I have a standalone PHP web app which consists of several pages in a checkout style process, the user posts a form on each page to the next with the collected data.

I am trying to port this to a Facebook Canvas app.

What is the best practice for posting forms from page to page in a Canvas app? Should I just post as normal with a form target of `_self`? If I do that though I understand I might not get the signed request on each page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, when you form post to _self, then you will not get a signed_request.  You should hold the user information in some server side storage such as a session object.

Comment: Is this the approach that people generally take then for creating multipage canvas apps?

Comment: Yep!  Sure is.  Happy Coding!